# AWS Lambda: How to call Mysql Query in sequence

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, node-mysql

I want to call more than one sql queries in sequence.
I have tried with below code but getting timeout error:

```
    exports.handler = function (event, context, callback) {

   getNumber()
    .then(result1 => {
        // Use result1
        return getNumber1(); // (A)
    })
    .then(result2 => { // (B)
        console.log(result2);
        callback(null, "OK");
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        callback(null, "OK");
    });
};

function getNumber() {

      return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

          connection.query("SELECT 1+1 as test ", (error, data) => {

            if (error) {
                reject(error);
            } else {
                resolve(data);
            }
            });
      }); 
    }

    function getNumber1() {

      return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

          connection.query("SELECT 1+2 as test ", (error, data) => {

            if (error) {
                reject(error);
            } else {
                resolve(data);
            }
            });
      }); 
    }
```

Here I'm getting '**Task timed out after 3.00 seconds**' error.
So anyone can help me to call connection.query synchronously.

Comment: Can you check whether it works for a single query?

Comment: @Ashan, single query, you mean to just call 'getNumber().then(....).catch(....) ?

Comment: Yes. Does it work? Just want to check whether the DB is accessible from Lambda.

Comment: @Ashan, I have updated my question by adding image for lambda function execution log. please check and kindly give you advice. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by chaining of AWS Lambda functions.
So in this case, each function has to be separated into different lambda functions. Then call them in a chain.

Still, keep in mind that Lambda functions have the time limit and will exit. So you may need different architecture/AWS component to achieve this if the Lambda running time is more.

[Invoke multiple aws lambda functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33411014/invoke-multiple-aws-lambda-functions)